# How do I get a WSDL file to work with an Flex 4.7 generated iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, coldfusion, wsdl, flex4

I have constructed an iPhone app using Flex 4.7. I have a WSDL file residing on a Coldfusion 10 server. When I preview the app with the Adobe Air iPhone simulator I receive data from the server. But when I run the same app from an iPhone I don not receive data from the server. Anyone have any ideas?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try access the wsdl via [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/)? What was return?

Regards!